# How do I prevent a form from submitting if two input fields do not have the same value?

Tags: jquery, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the following code to check if two input fields have the same value on form submit:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '.confirm-prescription', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const pharmacyCommentNew = $('#pharmacy_comment_new').val();
      const pharmacyComment = $('#pharmacy_comment').val();
    
      if (pharmacyCommentNew !== pharmacyComment || pharmacyCommentNew.length !== pharmacyComment.length) {
        enableSubmitButton();
        swal("Error", "Pharmacy comment has been modified. Please save the new comment before submitting.", "error");
        $('#ajax_loader').hide();
        return;
      }
    
      $('#ajax_loader').show();
      this.submit();
    });
function enableSubmitButton() {
  const submitButton = $('#resubmit-btn');
  submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
  submitButton.val('Submit');
}
```

However, I also want to disable the form submit button using the `data-disable-with` attribute when the form is submitted.
The button is being disabled properly, but it does not re-enable after the sweetalert alert is closed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed `if statement` so it's worked you can check with Code Snippet below

You can **try below code.**

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.confirm-prescription', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pharmacyCommentNew = $('#pharmacy_comment_new').val();
    const pharmacyComment = $('#pharmacy_comment').val();
    if (pharmacyCommentNew != pharmacyComment || (pharmacyCommentNew.length == 0 || pharmacyComment.length == 0)) {
        enableSubmitButton();
        console.log("Pharmacy comment has been modified. Please save the new comment before submitting.");
        return;
    }
    console.log('worked');
});
function enableSubmitButton() {
    const submitButton = $('#resubmit-btn');
    submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
    submitButton.val('Submit');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="confirm-prescription">
    <input type="text" id="pharmacy_comment_new" />
    <input type="text" id="pharmacy_comment" />
    <button name="submit" id="resubmit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```